# How to use VSTS Extension Splitter?

Tags: typescript, azure-devops

Please provide the examples for using VSTS Extension splitter ?

Below is  my TS file :

```
import Controls = require("VSS/Controls");
import { Splitter, ISplitterOptions } from "VSS/Controls/Splitter";

var container = $("<div />").attr("id", "UI-container").appendTo("#DefectCockpitContainer");
let options: ISplitterOptions = {

};
var splitter = Controls.create(Splitter, container, options)
```

MY html file has one container :

```
<div id="DefectCockpitContainer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About how to create a splitter, take a look at below TS code:

```
import Controls = require("VSS/Controls");
  import Splitter = require("VSS/Controls/Splitter");

  // Create the splitter in a container element
  var splitter = Controls.create<Splitter.Splitter, Splitter.ISplitterOptions>(Splitter.Splitter, container, options);
```

More details about how to use the splitter control, please refer this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/ui-controls/splittero?view=vsts), which shows different samples about the splitter control.

Comment: Working. Thank you

Comment: is there way where we can add two splitters  ?

Comment: @AnushaB Sorry, not sure about this, but haven't seen any samples about this area.